# how to convert an apk file to jar

Tags: android, jar, apk

I have an apk application but it's not working on my mobile?
And I tried it to convert by following steps:

1. I downloaded an apk file on my computer.
2. then I converted it to jar by dex2jar?
3. but it didn't worked on my mobile and a message shows "Invalid file".
4. then I open it in jd-gui and then save it to src file.
5. then I open it but all file shows as .java file.
   How to open it on my mobile?
   How to convert it to .class? 
   My mobile name is: samsung **gt-s3653**

Comment: dex2jar will convert an APK to a jar file. But the jar has references to Android framework components. This means it will NOT run on other mobiles. U need to download the jar version of the APP for your particular device and not the Apk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Android applications on Android devices. You cannot run Android applications on JavaME devices.